# Delete method in controller and delete buttons on the browser connection

Tags: php, methods, destroy

So I wish to have a warning message on my screen asking me if I want to delete an item in the inventory, if they click yes it will be deleted and redirected to the inventories list, however if I click no now it will delete and I want it to cancel and redirect back to the main inventories page. I'm unsure of how to do that.
Here is my delete and destroy methods in my controller:

```
/**
     * @param Inventory $inventory
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function delete(Inventory $inventory)
    {
        return view('pages.inventories.delete', ["inventory" => $inventory])
            ->with('warning', 'Do you wish to delete this item?');
        return redirect(destroy);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  Inventory $inventory
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Inventory $inventory): RedirectResponse
    {
        $inventory->delete();
        return redirect()->route('inventories.index')->with('success',
            'Item has been deleted!');
    }
```

Here is my delete.blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Delete Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1><strong>Delete inventory</strong></h1>
    {{ $inventory }}
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('/inventories', $inventory)}}">
       @method('delete')
        @csrf
        @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </div>
        @endif
        @if ($message = Session::get('warning'))
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-block">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </div>
        @endif
        <h3>Do you wish to delete this item?</h3>
        <button type="yes">Yes</button>
        <button type="no">No</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

My routers are fine and working but here they are just in case:

```
Route::get('/inventories/{inventory}/delete', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'delete'])->name('inventories.delete');

Route::delete('/inventories/{inventory}', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('inventories.destroy');
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In my delete.blade file I needed to do this in order to submit my form to destroy and item of inventory if 'yes' was clicked and if 'no' was clicked be redirected to the inventories page (main homepage).

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Delete Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1><strong>Delete inventory</strong></h1>
    {{ $inventory }}
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('/inventories', $inventory)}}">
       @method('delete')
        @csrf
        <button type="submit">Yes</button>
            <a href="/inventories">No</a>
    </form>
@endsection
```